# Set bindings on DB::raw

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I'm using Laravel 6.0 and I'm currently facing a problem when tring to bind parameters on a nested `DB:::raw`:

```
public static function search(string $value, string $field = 'product_name'){
    // this throws an exception because the bind is not effective and so the query has a problem
    return self::where(DB::raw("lower(?)"), "like", DB::raw('lower("%?%")'))->setBindings([$field ,$value ]);
    //this work, but always return an empty set
    return self::where(DB::raw("lower(:field)", ['field'=>$field]), "like", DB::raw('lower("%:value%")', ['value'=>$value]));
}
```

Both of those always retur an empty collection. Can someone please tell me why or suggest a workaround?

If i log the query, i see this:

```
QueryExecuted {#133 ▼
  +sql: "select count(*) as aggregate from `products` where lower(?) like lower("%?%")"
  +bindings: array:2 [▼
    0 => "product_name"
    1 => "a"
  ]
  +time: 1.04
  +connection: MySqlConnection {#135 ▶}
  +connectionName: "mysql"
}
```

Comment: But that query log is the expected result?

Comment: @mrhn yes, because if i takethat query and subsituct manually the values, it works perfectly, but something wrong is happening inside the bindings

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**Update**: I believe you don't need to use `lower`, because MySQL `like` will match case-insensitive by default, so simply use:

```php
return self::where($field, 'like', "%{$value}%");
```

---

It seems the problem is with double quot `"` that escapes the `?`, I think we can get rid of them using `concat`. Try `whereRaw` instead:

```php
return self::whereRaw('lower(?) like lower(concat("%", ?, "%"))', [$field, $value]);
```

Or:

```php
return self::whereRaw('lower(:field) like lower(concat("%", :value, "%"))', ['field' => $field, 'value' => $value]);
```

Comment: thanks for the answer... unfortunatly this solves only half of the problem, because now the "field" is """prepared""" (i mean substitucted) as  string literal...

Comment: however, that value is always passed by me, and not from outside, like user input, so i hope and believe that it's safe just to put it concatenating the string and not using params binding... however if you find a solution, please let me know, it will be so appreceated

Comment: @Berto99 I don't understand why are you using `lower` on your field name, why not just `self::where($field, 'like', "%{$value}%")` ? you know that `like` comparison is case-insensitive on MySQL.

Comment: Well.... seems like i've just lost 1 hour of work ahah thanks man